# Set cookie depending on domain in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have two domains and I want to set different languages for them. For domain.pl I want to set cookie lang=pl and for domain.eu I want lang=en, anyone know how to set it in .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these rules to write cookie that depends on domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

# set cookie lang=pl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,CO=lang:pl:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# set cookie lang=en
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,CO=lang:en:%{HTTP_HOST}]
```

Comment: yes, it works, thank you :) maybe you know how to make something like this: I want to redirect domain.pl/dog to domain.pl/cat and set language to pl, but for domain.pl/cow I want set language to en - any ideas?

Comment: Just add a rewrite rule below above 2 rules: `RewriteRule ^dog/?$ cow`